# How to get the number after particular string from array of strings using javascript?

Tags: javascript

below is an array of strings.

```
const arr = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "item/2/",
    "item/3/subitem/2/",
    "item/4/subitem/3/someother/5",
]
```

now i have to filter strings that has string starting with item/1/ and is not followed by any other string or is ending with string item/1/

so the expected filtered array is like below,

```
const filtered_array = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "item/2/",
]
```

from this filtered array i want to get only the number after item/ so the expected output is

```
const ids = ["1","2"]
```

i have tried below

```
var output = arr.filter(x => x.match(/^item\/\d+|\bitem\/\d+\/$/))
            .map(x => x.match(/(?<=^item\/)\d+|(?<=\bitem\/)\d+(?=\/$)/)[0]); //error 
            //here
```

this gives output like below

```
const output = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

because this matches also strings "item/3/subitem/2/",
"item/4/subitem/3/someother/5",

how can i fix this regex to match only strings starting with item/3/ and not followed by any other string or is ending with item/3/

also i get object is possibly null on map match line. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: *"now i have to filter strings that has string starting with item/1/ and is not followed by any other string or is ending with string item/1/"* How does `"item/2/"` in your expected result fit those rules?

Comment: thanks. here the number after item/ can be anything. so looking for string that matches either item/1/ or item/3/ or item/2/ so basically any number.

Comment: So basically, it's `item/<any_number>/` as long as it's at the end and `item` is a whole word? The other two don't match because it's not at the end?

Comment: yes thats right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `item/<any_number>`, but only if it's the last thing in the string. To do that, you'd use `/\bitem\/\d+\/$/`:

- `\b` means "word break" so we don't match `subitem`
- `item` matches the word item literally
- `\/` is how you write a `/` inside a regex so you match a `/` literally
- `\d` means "any digit"
- `+` means "one or more (of those digits)"
- `\/` is another literal `/`
- `$` means "end of input

Since you want to get the number from that, we'd wrap the `\d+` in `()` to make it a capture group. Then either use `map` to createa  map of either the matched string or `undefined` and then filter out `undefined` with `filter`:

```
const rex = /\bitem\/(\d+)\/$/;
const output = arr.map(str => (str.match(rex) ?? [])[1])
    .filter(result => result !== undefined);
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "item/2/",
    "item/3/subitem/2/",
    "item/4/subitem/3/someother/5",
];
const rex = /\bitem\/(\d+)\/$/;
const output = arr.map(str => (str.match(rex) ?? [])[1])
    .filter(result => result !== undefined);
console.log(output);
```

Or make just one pass through the data using a simple loop:

```
const rex = /\bitem\/(\d+)\/$/;
const output = [];
for (const str of arr) {
    const match = str.match(rex);
    if (match) {
        output.push(match[1]);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "item/2/",
    "item/3/subitem/2/",
    "item/4/subitem/3/someother/5",
];
const rex = /\bitem\/(\d+)\/$/;
const output = [];
for (const str of arr) {
    const match = str.match(rex);
    if (match) {
        output.push(match[1]);
    }
}
console.log(output);
```

---

Note that that would match `"sub-item/1/"`, though. If you want to require that `item` be either at the beginning of the string or just after a `/`, we change the `\b` to `(?:^|\/)` to say "beginning of string or `/`" (the `(?:___)` is just to group the alternation [`|`]): `/(?:^|\/)item\/(\d+)\/$/`

Comment: thanks a ton. how could we get the number only after item/ from the output?

Comment: @stackuser - Sorry, missed that. Do you need the intermediate array (`filtered_array`), or is your goal to just to get the numbers?

Comment: goal is to just the get numbers and put it to new array from the filtered array of strings.